# Prove that $\operatorname{cl}\big(A\cap\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{fr}A)\big)=\operatorname{cl}\big(\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{fr}A)\big)$

Tags: general-topology

Let be $X$ a topological space: so I am trying to prove that
$$
\operatorname{cl}\big(A\cap\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{fr}A)\big)=\operatorname{cl}\big(\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{fr}A)\big)
$$
for any $A\in\mathcal P(X)$.

So first of all I observed that $A\cap\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{fr}A)$ is contained in $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{fr}A)$ so that
$$
\operatorname{cl}\big(A\cap\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{fr}A)\big)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}\big(\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{fr}A)\big)
$$
However unfortunately I am not able to prove the reverse inclusion, that is I am not able to prove that
$$
\operatorname{cl}\big(\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{fr}A)\big)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}\big(A\cap\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{fr}A)\big)
$$
So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 4):

In order to show $\subseteq$, you just need to show that every point $x\in\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{Fr}(A))$ belongs to the closure of $A\cap\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{Fr}(A))$.

This is equivalent to requiring that every open neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A\cap\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{Fr}(A))$.

Take an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and consider $U'=U\cap\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{Fr}(A))$. Then $U'$ consists of points of $\operatorname{Fr}(A)$ and $U'$ is an open set so it must contain a point $a\in A$.

Therefore $a\in A\cap U'\subseteq A\cap\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{Fr}(A))$, but also $a\in U$ and so $U\cap(A\cap\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{Fr}(A))\ne\emptyset$ as required.

Thus we proved that $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{Fr}(A))\subseteq\operatorname{cl}(A\cap\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{Fr}(A)))$ and we're done.

Comment: The "point" is that if $x\in int (Fr(A))$ then $U'$ is  a non-empty open set with $U'\subset Fr(A)\subset \overline A,$ so $U'\cap A$ is not empty.....+1

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the notation $\overline A$ is equivalent to saying cl (A) in the notation that is used in the original question to avoid any potential confusion.

Comment: @FD_bfa Fixed, I overlooked.